# Using one nginx config file for all websites

Tags: nginx, configuration, reverse-proxy

I have a server where there is a control panel installed, with about 100 webpages/domains.
It doesn't support nginx, so i want to install nginx as reverse proxy.
But how can I configure, that it uses a central nginx configuration,
So that I don't need to create virt. conf vor every domain?

Can i use [this tutorial](http://www.dikant.de/2008/07/10/nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-apache/)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use wildcard (*) for 'ServerName' value and that's all IMHO. All requests will go through NginX (because you have wildcard) and look for Apache VirtualHost configuration.